# Change monitor RGB color using assembly language MIPS

Tags: assembly, colors, mips, monitor, vga

I wanted to create a project in assembly language. I studied MIPS using MARS on windows. All we learned was about the language itself and and all that text and number based programs to understand it. Now I want use it to experiment by changing my monitor RGB color.
I have no lead on it. I tried searching like controlling colors or vga programming but nothing found for MIPS assembly language. Kindly guide that can it be done using it and how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should understand the difference between MARS and a real MIPS processor:

**Real MIPS processors**

A real MIPS processor executes machine code instructions (which are represented by assembler instructions).

As soon as the `syscall` instruction is called the CPU goes into some "special" state and starts executing the operating system code. The OS also consists of MIPS instructions.

The OS typically will do something depending on the values stored in the registers. However the OS could also be written in a way that it ignores the values in the registers...

By reading and writing data from or to "special" addresses (e.g. using the `lw` instruction) the OS can access peripherals (such as the keyboard, the screen, ...). It depends on the hardware which "special" address has which meaning.

**MARS, SPIM, ...**

These emulators only simulate machine code instructions.

When the `syscall` instruction is called these simulators do **not** start operating system code which consists of MIPS instructions. Instead these emulators will perform some action based on the values in the registers.

Example:

Some simulator might print the value in the register `a0` to the screen if the register `v0` contains the value 1.

Because there is no OS typically there are **no** "special" addresses for accessing peripherals (such as the display) using instructions like `lw`.

**The effect**

Unlike MIPS code on a real CPU you cannot do everything which can be done with the computer using such an emulator.

These emulators are typically written to test MIPS programs for students who are learning MIPS assembly. They are not written to allow programmers to write powerful programs.

Therefore these emulators typically don't have very powerful features.

MAYBE your emulator allows colored output; however it is very likely that your emulator does not have this feature...

Comment: Thanks for a detailed comment and sorry for somewhat foolish question. I see where I got my self wrong. May I delete the question. It maybe misleading and degraded my reputation as well. I will be careful next time.